# How to send Notification to React Native (mobile) app from Django (back-end)

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am developing a mobile application using React Native. and using Django as a back-end Language. I want to know how I can send notifications from Django to React native mobile application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about iOS/Android notifications or sending data to the app whilst it's running through something like a websocket?

Comment: Yes, of course, looking something like WebSocket, that user should not need to refresh the android/IOS screen and get a notification. But the main thing is that I want to know how I can throw the notification towards the Native (android/IOS ) application from Django?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have channels in your project then just go ahead and create a model, an api, and a schedule api check in react so you check all new things in notification api to push up to the client

Comment: Well, your opinion is also perfect, But It require running continuous background tasks (function). and it can cause to slow down app and user mobile phone

Comment: if u want to have notifications in real time u need channel otherwise u should go for a scheduled function